# This.setstate unmounts within a callback

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Really confused here. I updated to React Router 4 which required a few changes and now when my registration form errors on the server side it returns the console error:

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This
>   usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op. Please check the code for the RegisterForm component.

What's really confusing is if I run `this.setState({ errors: {createUserError: "Test error" }});` outside of `Accounts.createUser` function I don't get the consolde error.

Any suggestions????

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({errors: {} }, function() {
      var data = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      };

        Accounts.createUser(data, (error) => {   // This arrow function preserves this
        if(error) {
          this.setState({ errors: {createUserError: error.reason }});
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You will need to provide more context or figure out why you component is unmounted. As @GProst stated in his comment, this type of state most likely belongs outside of the component, and it seems that you should wait until the login outcome is clear before navigating away from the login view.

Comment: I've been able to track down the problem. It was linked with Public/Authenticated routes component that caused the component to unmount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this could happened when your component has been unmounted before your second setState is called. Maybe `Accounts.createUser()` triggers router navigation or something else that unmounts your component.

Comment: How would I mount it again?

Comment: It means you have removed the component yourself. In general the best solution is to move the state out of the component. Therefore you won't have to check whether it's mounted or not.

Comment: Unmounted component is a component, that isn't displayed on the html page. If unmounting this component is reasonable, then maybe you shouldn't try do anything with it after it is unmounted? If unmounting isn't reasonable, then you should prevent it.

Comment: Is it possible for someone to put up a solution.