# How to stop callback from unmounting component

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Really confused here. I updated to React Router 4 which required a few changes and now when my registration form errors on the server side it returns the console error:
this is the callback.

> setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This
>   usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is
>   a no-op. Please check the code for the RegisterForm component.

What's really confusing is if I run `this.setState({ errors: {createUserError: "Test error" }});` outside of `Accounts.createUser` function I don't get the consolde error.

Any suggestions????

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({errors: {} }, function() {
      var data = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
      };

        Accounts.createUser(data, (error) => {   // This arrow function preserves this
        if(error) {
          this.setState({ errors: {createUserError: error.reason }});
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Duplicate of [This.setstate unmounts within a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44150077/this-setstate-unmounts-within-a-callback). Please don't double-post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time the HTTP request generated by `Accounts.createUser` returns the error, the component that `handleSubmit` is bound to is unmounted, which is why calling `setState` generates the error.

One option is to move `handleSubmit` to a parent that doesn't get unmounted on form submission and to pass the function down as a prop. Another option is to use redux or flux for state management.

Another option is to keep the component mounted until `Accounts.createUser` returns successfully, which will allow you to display messages on the form in case of an error. For example, you could indicate which fields are invalid.